# different distance values for a route-segment

Tags: android, mapquest

I am developing a turn by turn navigation app with mapquest API for android.I start the navigation process, and the distance of the route-segment says, for example,"turn right/left in 20 meters". But, when I tried displaying the distance change continuously(by calculating distance between current position and next geopoint where a turn has to occur), it gives me different values for the route-segment. I used the "Location.distanceBetween()" to find the distance. Should i implement some other logic for calculation ?

Thanks,
Gokul

Answer (score 0):

Is there not an API you can use to get the remaining distance? Maybe you register a listener that recieves periodic callbacks?

Location.distanceBetween isn't a great option. If you have a large turn or a lot of turns, the straight line that distanceBetween calculates won't be anything close to the actual road distance.

Comment: Do you know of any such API? i have used a locationlistener, and use the associated callbacks

Comment: Sorry, I meant a MapQuest API, I'd assumed that the API had that functionality. Are you just using their web directions API (http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/)? If so, I think your best bet is to take the shape data of the current route segment to figure out how far away you are. Take the distance between each point in the shape data and add them up to get the distance for the entire segment.